# Сравнение текстов

Tags: diff

Есть задача:

1. Берется код из хранилища.
2. Сохраняется текстовым файлом before.txt. (для начала вручную)
3. В него вносятся изменения.
4. Получившийся файл сохраняем как after.txt.
5. Сравниваем два текста и автоматически обкладываем каждое изменение комментариями.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь софт(плагин) имеющий последнюю функцию(os не принципиальна)
Пример:
**Было:**

```
Самый хитрый  
из людей- это сказочник   
злодей
```

**Пользователь исправил на:**

```
Самый хитрый  
из людей- это сказочник   
добряк
```

**После обработки должно стать:**

```
Самый хитрый  
из людей- это сказочник  
// Начало изменений от 12 марта пользователем Марк   
добряк  
// Конец изменений от 12 марта пользователем Марк
```

Comment: утилита diff? вот только что понимается под "автоматически обкладываем комментариями" - я не знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня есть смутное подозрение что это значит: были строки 1 и 2 в тексте. Строку 2 стерли и написали строку 3. В результате после обработки должны в файле остаться строки 1, 2 и закомментированная строка 3. Хотя лучше пусть ТС объяснит.

Comment: Посмотри в сторону WinMerge, WinDiff, Araxis Merge, Beyond Compare, и т.п.

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Comment: Почитайте `man diff`. Думаю, взять за основу анализ вывода `diff -e ...` это именно то, что Вам нужно.